# Setka - Complete grid using clues and sudoku-style logic; Theme - Greenwich Village Resident

Tags: logical-deduction, word, wordplay, crosswords

This is a Setka puzzle; you can find more (along with a more detailed explanation of the rules) at our website, linked from our profile.

Theme: Greenwich Village Resident

How to play Setka, the short version:

Answer each clue using only Puzzle Letters and vowels.

Clue answers, minus vowels and duplicate letters, go in the corresponding boxes in the grid. Only Puzzle Letters go in the grid!

Puzzle Letters can be entered forward/backward/up/down/L-shape, but not jumbled. They also cannot repeat in a row or column.

Enjoy!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers are

> 1. DN (for Edna) 
>  2. NS (for New School) 
>  3. TRD (for Torrid) 
>  4. ST (for status) 
>  5. RN (for Reno) 
>  6. D (for Eddie) 
>  
>  7. STR (for Street) 
>  8. NR (for near) 
>  9. STD (for Sated) 
>  10. STRND (for Strand)

Completed grid:

> N D S R T 
>  T S N D R 
>  D R T S N 
>  R N D T S 
>  S T R N D

Comment: Great job! For clue 4:
4. The average and median salary and __________ of village residents has skyrocketed. 
We had "assets" as the answer - but status may be even better! Thanks for playing.

Comment: Thanks! We will keep posting them here and on our website. Free to play!